# Count files in a Google Drive folder in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive

I am managing a construction project where we have to replace 6500 lead lines with copper from curb to inside meter. I have inspectors getting the right of entry and preconstruction pictures daily for each house and then scheduling the work for the replacement crews.

We are running into issues where for some reason the inspectors pictures do not upload to the respective google drive folder.

While doing their schedule in google sheets, I have the google drive link pop up for the house. **I also want the file count to show up so they can notice if pictures are missing**. 99% of the time there's only 1 file which is the right of entry form but no pictures.

This is very frustrating because is a customer complains about something after construction, I have no way of referencing.